# Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined post.comments

Tags: node.js

I am running into the error `Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined post.comments` in the below code:

```
const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);

const newComment = {
  text: req.body.text,
  name: user.name,
  user: req.user.id
};

post.comments.unshift(newComment)

await post.save();
res.json(post.comments);
```

Comment: `post.comments` is undefined.

Comment: Are you sure your post document is found? It might be undefined.

Comment: how have you defined the post model need to see that as well.. because post.comments is not an array it seems that is why you are unable to unshift it and yes also to note that ```post.findById()``` returns a document..

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `post.comments` could be empty at first, i.e., not even be defined. So you will need to handle that:

```
post.comments instanceof Array ? post.comments.unshift(newComment) : post.comments = [newComment];
```

But you should also add a guard in case the post was not even found in first place:

```
!post && res.end('error: post not found')
```

or similar, ideally also add a `statusCode`.

Comment: thk u so so so so much <3<3<3<3<3<3<3

Comment: Glad it helped. Please don't forget to upvote and/or accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `post.comments` is not an Array when you are checking. It is most likely undefined.

You can check first:

```
if (Array.isArray(post.comments)) {
  post.comments.unshift();
}
```

You can also do a shorthand check:

```
(post.comments || []).unshift();
```

This will check if post.comments is defined, and if not will create an array first. This will make sure it won't be undefined.